# The answer to this puzzle is…

Tags: lateral-thinking

What is the answer?

Hints:

- This puzzle is too vague
- This puzzle is still incomplete
- There is not enough information to determine the answer
- When this puzzle is complete the answer will read as clear as day
- Come back later

Comment: flag/close? ha.

Comment: I'm tempted to just edit something into the title and then answer with it, but that might be a little too meta.

Comment: I'm magical! The prophet has appeared.

Comment: Great. Way to create a paradox. The puzzle no longer has too many answers, but were it to be reopened, it would have too many answers. Internal conflict, commence!

Comment: Damn I have another valid answer to this. Guess I was too late.

Comment: ....alright, I've got to give it to you, this is pretty clever.

Comment: If only I had enough reputation... I would instantly vote to reopen this post :')

Comment: Hahahha - Marco would vote to re-open this post!  Then it would be wrong and we'd have to close it because there's no possible solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

> [on hold], or eventually [closed]

because

> the title is shortly going to read "The answer to this puzzle is… [on hold]"

Answer (score 6):

The anwser is

> too broad

Because a puzzle satisfying any/all of the hints will lead to:

> a close request with the tick on "too broad"

Comment: Somewhat along those lines, but focus on the "completeness" part of the puzzle. What has to be completed?

Comment: It would be great if you could answer that before my question actually gets closed :)

Comment: @Ivan: What has to be completed is the closing itself, isn't it?

Comment: Because of technical reasons, the ellipsis were being displayed incorrectly, now things should make sense (I guess)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> as clear as day

Because

> When this puzzle is complete the answer will read **as clear as day**

Comment: I overlooked this solution while making that last one clue, well done! But not what I intended

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> An ellipsis (**...**)

*This puzzle is too vague*

> An ellipsis can be used to describe something vaguely

*This puzzle is still incomplete*

> An ellipsis can indicate that a field on a webpage contains more text (is incomplete)

*There is not enough information to determine the answer*

> An ellipsis indicates a lack of information

*When this puzzle is complete the answer will read as clear as day*

> The puzzle is already complete, and the answer is there in the title, as clear as day.